# Unexpected Output while trying yo convert String to date using FastDateFormat

Tags: java, date, apache-commons-lang3

Problem:

I need to pass Date class Object to a function and that Date Object should contain one Day ahead of the System Time.
For Ex:
 If Today's Date is 2017-04-20 17:01:31.Then,Date Object should contain 2017-04-21 17:01:31

> Is it possible to store a specified format into Date Class Object and pass into it.

I tried the following thing and it didn't work.

> Can anyone guide me if it is possible through Code or should I use SQL Query Concept to add a Day.

Below is my Code

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
            String s2=addDate(dateFormat);
            convertStringToDate(s2,dateFormat);

        }
    public static Date convertStringToDate(String dateInStr, String dateFormat) throws ParseException
    {
        FastDateFormat fdf=FastDateFormat.getInstance(dateFormat);//("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = null;
        date = fdf.parse(dateInStr);
        System.out.println("From convertStringToDate ");
        System.out.println(date);
        return date;
    }
public static String addDate(String dateFormat) throws ParseException{
            FastDateFormat fdf=FastDateFormat.getInstance(dateFormat);
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();    
            c.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
            String s1=fdf.format(c.getTime());
            System.out.println("From addDate ");
            System.out.println(s1);
            return s1;
        }
```

Expected Output from convertStringToDate:

```
2017-04-21 17:01:31
```

OutputShown from convertStringToDate:

```
Fri Apr 21 17:01:31 IST 2017
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is the actual output, what is the expected output?

Comment: "Is it possible to store a specified format into Date Class Object" <- The date class does not have a format, it just contains the data to represent the date. How you format that data when you display it in a GUI is another thing.

Comment: @RC.Edited the code

Comment: @RC. Yes But IT Should be in Date Class

Comment: No, the format used when a Date is printed via Date#toString is not yours to choose, if you really need that, then use some wrapper around date and a proper Wrapper#toString

Comment: @RC. Can explain with implementation please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse String to Date using FastDateFormat in a specified format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43513600/how-to-parse-string-to-date-using-fastdateformat-in-a-specified-format)

Comment: Even though `FastDateFormat` seems to have som advantages over `SimpleDateFormat`, in 2017 I recommend using the newer Java date and time classes, including `DateTimeFormatter`, which is thread-safe too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to obtain the instance of class Date. In your method `addDate` you get the required Date and then convert it to `String` and return a `String`. And then you convert your `String` back to `Date` Why don't you just return `Date` from your method `addDate` and be done with it?